# How do I move a div from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have the following div on a page called Transactions.html :

```
<div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a">
        <h3>$12.62   -  11/01/2012   -   Kelloggs Diner  -  Brooklyn Ny</h3>
        <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
            <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">Yes</a>
            <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
            <a class="blue" href="IDK.html" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button">I'm not sure</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I click the link `<a>No</a>` I want the whole div to move to another Summary.html page.  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Kind of a primitive way: you could use jQuery to disable visibility on the class you set for this div, say "theListItem", then enable visibility on a class you set for the div on transactions.html, say "theListItem_summary"... and of course have the HTML code on both pages. But that's not really "moving" it.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. You need to have a wrapper div tag in-order to select the entire html content.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.red').click(function(){
            var divData = $('#dataContainer').html();
        window.location.href = "summarypage.html?data="+divData+"";
        });
    });            
</script>

<div id="dataContainer">
    <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a">
            <h3>$12.62   -  11/01/2012   -   Kelloggs Diner  -  Brooklyn Ny</h3>
            <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
                <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">Yes</a>
                <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">No</a>
                <a class="blue" href="IDK.html" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button">I'm not sure</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In summary page you need to retrieve the data from the URL. When you run this and click 'NO' link it navigates to summary page and you can see the html values on the summary page URL bar

You can use PHP to retrieve this data using `<?php echo $_REQUEST['data']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't - that's not how the web works. Each HTML page is self-contained and encapsulated.

Some sites, like Github, do little tricks with the JavaScript history API and AJAX to make it appear as though a new page is "partially loaded", when in fact it's the same page.

Comment: There must be a way to click a link on one page, and than effect another.  For instance click a link `<a>Blue</a>` on blue.html and change the background-color on canvas.html from white to blue.  How do I do that?

Comment: CSS and jQuery. select the class with jQ using $('class_name')
then change it's css properties by appending .css(properties go here)
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use PHP or a server side technology for storing data and that needs complete transformation of your static pages to dynamic PHP pages, that needs lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

By using the html it is not possible to transfer the data from one html file to another html file. use the JQuery to perform the data transfer
By clicking on the button, speficy in which div or place you want the data to display, by using the load() in Jquery you can load the specific data in another page to your page